# How to update m2m objects with django formsets?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm starting this project in which I have an Order class with an m2m relationship with an Item class using the throug argument with an ItemTimes class. The idea is to add several items to an order registering also it times. For that I use a model formset. The creation of the order goes well but to update items I can't even get to the point in which the formset is valid. Printing the formset errors throws this: [{'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'id': ['This field is required.']}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] but in the indexes where says "This Field is required" is where ItemTimes objects are selected. Help please.

Here models.py

```
    """orders models"""

# django
from django.db import models

# local
from ..customers.models import Customer
from ..kits.models import Kit
from ..items.models import Item
from ..executors.models import Executor


class Order(models.Model):
    """Pre Bill document to register job details performed"""
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Cliente")
    symptom = models.CharField('Síntoma', max_length=100)
    flaw = models.CharField('Defecto', max_length=100)
    repair_description = models.CharField('Reparación', max_length=100)
    folio = models.CharField('No. folio', max_length=10)
    # next four attributes are related to the modality of the order
    check_diagnosis = models.BooleanField('Revisión/Diagnóstico')
    repair = models.BooleanField('Reparacón')
    install = models.BooleanField('Instal./Mont./Desmont.')
    maintenance = models.BooleanField('Mtto')
    # end of modality set
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Equipo")
    kit_brand = models.CharField('Marca', max_length=20)
    kit_model = models.CharField('Modelo', max_length=20)
    kit_serial = models.CharField('No. de serie o Inv.', max_length=20)
    job_description = models.TextField('Descripción del trabajo realizado', blank=True, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(
        Item,
        through='ItemTimes',
        verbose_name='Artículo o Servicio',
        editable=False,
        blank=True
    )
    executor = models.ForeignKey(
        Executor,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Ejecutor'
    )
    # customer_charge = models.CharField('Cargo', max_length=25)
    # customer_name = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=25)
    # customer_personal_id = models.CharField('No. CI', max_length=11)
    executor_signature_date = models.DateField('Fecha')
    customer_signature_date = models.DateField('Fecha')
    # attribute to deal with deactivation instead of deletion 
    # when an objetc has relationships
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['executor_signature_date']
        verbose_name = 'Orden de Servicio'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Órdenes de Servicio'
    
    def __str__(self):
        """Returns  the string object representation"""
        return self.customer.name



class ItemTimes(models.Model):
    """Class to register how many items go in an order"""
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Artículo", null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    times = models.PositiveIntegerField('Cantidad', default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cantidad de Artículo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cantidades de Artículo'
    
    def __str__(self):
        """Returns  the string object representation"""
        return self.item.name + ' - ' + self.order.customer.name
```

views.py

```
"""orders views"""

# django
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

# local
from .forms import OrderForm
from .models import Order, ItemTimes


class OrderList(generic.ListView):
    """Class for listing Orders objects."""
    model = Order
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'orders/list.html'


class OrderCreate(generic.CreateView):
    """Class for creating Orders objects."""
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm
    template_name = 'orders/create_or_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders:list')

    def get(self, request):
        ItemTimesFormSet = modelformset_factory(ItemTimes, exclude=['order'], extra=5)
        formset = ItemTimesFormSet(queryset=ItemTimes.objects.none())

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'form': self.get_form(),
            'formset': formset,
        })
    
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        ItemTimesFormSet = modelformset_factory(ItemTimes, exclude=['order'], extra=5)
        formset = ItemTimesFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            order = Order(**form.cleaned_data)
            order.save()

            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data.get('item'):
                    item = form.cleaned_data.get('item')
                    times = form.cleaned_data.get('times')
                    item_times = ItemTimes(
                        item = item,
                        order = order,
                        times = times,
                    )
                    item_times.save()
            
            return redirect(self.success_url)


class OrderUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    """Class for updating Orders objects."""
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm
    template_name = 'orders/create_or_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders:list')

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        item_times = ItemTimes.objects.filter(order=order)
        ItemTimesFormSet = modelformset_factory(ItemTimes, exclude=('order',), extra=5)
        formset = ItemTimesFormSet(queryset=item_times)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'form': self.form_class(instance=order),
            'formset': formset
        })
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        ItemTimesFormSet = modelformset_factory(ItemTimes, exclude=['order'], extra=5)
        formset = ItemTimesFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            print('valid')
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            print(formset.errors)
            return redirect(self.success_url)


class OrderDelete(generic.DeleteView):
    """Class for deleting Orders objects"""
    model = Order
    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders:list')
```

and the template

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block navbar_links %}
{% include 'snippets/dropdowns.html' %}
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{% url 'orders:list' %}" class="nav-link">Órdenes de Servicio</a>
</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


{% include './snippets/header.html' %}

    <form method="post" class="row">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        <!-- customer control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.customer|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.customer|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.customer.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.customer.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- symptom control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.symptom|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.symptom|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.symptom.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.symptom.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- flaw control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.flaw|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.flaw|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.flaw.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.flaw.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- repair_description control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.repair_description|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.repair_description|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.repair_description.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.repair_description.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- folio control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.folio|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.folio|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.folio.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.folio.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9"></div>
        <!-- check_diagnosis control -->
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
            {{form.check_diagnosis|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.check_diagnosis|add_class:"form-check"}}
            {% if form.check_diagnosis.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.check_diagnosis.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- repair control -->
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
            {{form.repair|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.repair|add_class:"form-check"}}
            {% if form.repair.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.repair.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- install control -->
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
            {{form.install|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.install|add_class:"form-check"}}
            {% if form.install.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.install.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- maintenance control -->
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
            {{form.maintenance|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.maintenance|add_class:"form-check"}}
            {% if form.maintenance.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.maintenance.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <!-- kit control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.kit|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.kit|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.kit.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.kit.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- kit_brand control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.kit_brand|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.kit_brand|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.kit_brand.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.kit_brand.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- kit_model control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.kit_model|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.kit_model|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.kit_model.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.kit_model.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- kit_serial control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.kit_serial|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.kit_serial|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.kit_serial.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.kit_serial.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- job_description control -->
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 mb-2">
            {{form.job_description|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.job_description|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.job_description.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.job_description.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- items_times control -->
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 mb-2">
        <!-- {{formset}} -->
        {% for form in formset %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {{form.item|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
                {{form.item|add_class:"form-select"}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                {{form.times|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
                {{form.times|add_class:"form-control"}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- executor control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.executor|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.executor|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {% if form.executor.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.executor.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- executor_signature_date control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.executor_signature_date|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.executor_signature_date|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"type:date"}}
            {% if form.executor_signature_date.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.executor_signature_date.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- customer_signature_date control -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            {{form.customer_signature_date|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
            {{form.customer_signature_date|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"type:date"}}
            {% if form.customer_signature_date.errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.customer_signature_date.errors %}
                    <li class="form-text text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- buttons -->
        <div class="mb-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" value="Guardar">
            {% if order.id %}
            <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#deleteKitModal">Eliminar</button>
            {% endif %}
            <a href="{% url 'orders:list' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </form>


{% if order.id %}
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteKitModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteKitModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteKitModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>¿Está seguro de eliminar el la orden: {{order.customer.name}}?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <form action="{% url 'orders:delete' order.pk %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" value="Eliminar">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should `exclude=('order',)` in your Order Update Get function be `['order']?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine gave me the answer, when rendering forms manually it must be included {{form.id}} within each form iteration. In my case it'll be this way.

```
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="row">
    {{form.id}}
    <div class="col-md-10">
        {{form.item|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
        {{form.item|add_class:"form-select"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
        {{form.times|add_label_class:"form-label"}}
        {{form.times|add_class:"form-control"}}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```